# Filling array with map function issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand how to fill the array with a `map()` with the one difference:
I have array which is filled  with a template like :

```
const templateOfRanks = {
  rankingElementsTemplate : [
    {row : [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]},
    {row : [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9]},
    {row : [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4]},
  ]
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBrR8.png)
It looks like a dimensional array. How can I fill a new array without "rows"? I want to get an array with elements from this template but without nested elements.
It should look like: `[ 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9,3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4]`

Probably I should use the `push()` function, I don't know...but I need to have two arrays: the first one is dimensional and the second one is single. 
Help me, please.

Comment: `Array.prototype.flatMap()`

Comment: Or just a plain old `for` loop. At least give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use flatMap

```
const templateOfRanks = {
  rankingElementsTemplate : [
    {row : [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]},
    {row : [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9]},
    {row : [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4]},
  ]
}

const flat = templateOfRanks.rankingElementsTemplate.flatMap(i => i.row);
console.log(flat);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you tell me please, how can I use this for nested objects? For example, instead of rows this structure of array: Array [ 0 [ {..}], 1 [ {..}] etc.

Comment: can you post an sample of the structure?

Comment: Array: 0:[ [{value : 1.1, state = false}], [{value : 1.2, state = false}], [{value : 1.3, state = false}];
1:[ [{value : 2.1, state = false}], [{value : 2.2, state = false}], [{value : 3.3, state = false}];
2:[[{value : 3.1, state = false}], [{value : 3.2, state = false}]; 
etc. This is a dimensional array with nested objects

Comment: look at the picture, please:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cT_rcFufMLXH7q-nnPaFzpjYLHggGGw-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you post another question with the correct structure?

Comment: I've just attached the picture

Comment: D. Seah@ I found the solution:
`var myNewArray3 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; ++j)
    myNewArray3.push(myArray[i][j]);
}`
It helped to me. Thanks for your activity.